# pythonからツイートの保存について

Tags: python, twitter

下記のツイートを保存したいのですが上手くいきません。実行中でpython intento.py >> result.dat
を書きました。

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import json

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
access_token = 'access_token_example'
access_token_secret = 'access_token_secret'
consumer_key = 'comsumer_srcret_example'
consumer_secret = 'consumer_secret_example'


# This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        json_load = json.loads(data)
        texts = json_load['text']
        coded = texts.encode('utf-8')
        s = str(coded)
        print(s[2:-1])
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, StdOutListener())

# This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords:                 'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
OKINAWA = [127.672482, 26.088887, 128.275025, 26.851451]
stream.filter(track=[u'臺灣', ],languages=['ja'], locations=OKINAWA)
```

実行
[root@localhost デスクトップ]#python intento.py
0o8m3o1e 
ありがとー��
2tNC9CYlGoicJz ひんすーだから少金額からやるのさ残りの口座がくみてみ積み上げていけば良いのさ���
�い…��ANS_AMRAI @hanaFFRK 犯すのはまえはなだけにしてください
�じ前の車のクラウン運転してる人頭悪��
python intento.py >> result.dat

デスクトップにあるファイル（result.dat）を開くと、何も表示されません。
もしやり方がわかる方いれば、教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

on_dataを下記のように変更して、`python intento.py >> result.txt`と実行してみてください

```
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data[2:-1])
        return True
```

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

実行したプログラムを`CTRL+C`で止めると出力されるのではないでしょうか？
この場合、print()の出力がバッファリングされているのが原因です。

以下、現象を再現できる最小のサンプルです。

test_print.py

```
import time

while True:
    print("a")
    time.sleep(1)
```

`python test_print.py >> result.dat` で実行して、別のコンソールから`tailf result.dat`で出力を見ても実行中は何も出力されませんが、CTRL+Cで止めると出力されます。

### 解決方法

`print("a", flush=True)`とすればprintを呼び出したタイミングで即座に出力されるようになります。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございました。

Comment: 「ありがとうございました」だけだと状況がわかりません。 コメントを書くのなら、解決したのかどうか、何か変化があったのかどうか、等を書いて下さい。 もし回答が役に立って解決したのなら、回答を承認して下さい。 他の方法で自己解決したのなら、自分で回答を追加してそれを承認して下さい。 [回答を承認するとどうなりますか？](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%82%92%E6%89%BF%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)